# Floating DIV elements is not lining up

Tags: jquery, css

I have dives that I am floating so that they show side by side. Here is my code:

```
.serviceMembersPosition {
    width: 190px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

It works however if one of the DIV's has more info than the others, it stuffs up the floats. See how there is a gap in my screenshot below. Is there any way to overcome this? I am using JQuery with my website. Maybe there is some code for this?

[alt text http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/1032/screenshot20100331at110.png](http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/1032/screenshot20100331at110.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue seems to be a line wrapping problem. Some of your descriptions take up 2 lines compared to those that take up 1 line. Try using a plug-in that can handle this.

[Setting Equal Heights with jQuery](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/)

Comment: Since my design width is fluid not fixed, putting clear: both after every 3 items won't work so this is the way I'll have to go :) Appreciate all your answers!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid that, you need to clear the float after every "row".

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Insert a DIV like that before any DIV that you want to be the left-most one in the current row.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is normal behaviour ..

a simple css trick is to `clear:left` every three items (since you have 3 boxes per row)

in css3

```
.serviceMembersPosition:nth-child(3n+1){clear:left;}
```

since few browsers support css3 you can use the jquery equivalent

```
$('.serviceMembersPosition:nth-child(3n+1)').css('clear','left')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;​
```

but still IE fails to render correctly..

for IE you will have to either wrap each row in a div and set `overflow:auto` to it or put a clearing div / br after each row with a css rule that has `clear:both`